# How can I enable DirectX 10 support for Star Trek Online in wine

Tags: drivers, graphics, wine, video, games

I was able to play Star Trek Online using Wine since oktober 2016.
Suddenly (Feb. 2017) Star Trek Online complains about lack of DirectX 10 support:

Error message:

> Support for the Video Card you are using will end on March 1, 2017. You will >be unable to play using this Video Card after support ends. Please upgrade >your Video Card to one that supports DirectX Hardware Feature Level 10 or >higher; See your Video Card manufacture's documentation for information on >DirektX Hardware Feature Level support.

My Hardware:
Prozessor: AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD Radeon
Grafik: Gallium 0.4 on AMD MULLINS (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)
64 Bit
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Here's a discussion about it: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/4v5vnc/whats_the_holdup_with_dx10_support_in_wine/

Comment: Running STO via Wine is not guaranteed to work at all.  I've had limited success installing STO via Steam and using Steam Play, however it's still not functional to a level that is really acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

On March 1st 2017, STO dropped support for DX9.

I had a similar issue, and got STO partially working following this: https://www.reddit.com/r/sto/comments/5tpghw/psa_for_linuxmac_users_sto_dx11_now_works_under/

It had startup issues for me (This is a fresh STO and Linux install), so to get around them, I configured an emulated desktop of 1024x768 in the WINE settings, then when STO started in the emulated desktop (in fullscreen mode), I chose windowed mode in STO, then exited STO, removed the emulated desktop in WINE, and it worked.. Sort of.

When I logged in, my character was in ESD, and the picture looked bad. I found that by disabling lighting 2.0 in the graphics settings, the picture got about 80% better, but still not totally back to normal.

I logged out after some fleet chat, and have not yet tried to run any missions.